# Angular 4 updating view on array push

Tags: angular

It looks like this problem is popular, I tried many times to update my view after a new `element` pushed in my array, but nothing happened.

I will explain my functions and what I'm trying to do, and I will show you my tries.

My first component is `car.component.ts` that I used to show my cars list calling API using `carsService`.

```
carsList() {
        this._carsListService.carsService(this.user)
            .subscribe(
                response => {
                        this.result = response;
                        if (this.result.code != 200) {
                             //error response message
                        }
                        else if (this.result.code == 200) {
                            this.data = [] = this.data;
                            this.result.cars.forEach(element => {
                                this.data.push(element);
                            });
                        }
                },
                error => console.log(error)
            );
    }
```

Second component is `insert.component.ts` that I can add a new car with details and the carsList should detect the changes which is what I'm looking for.

```
insertNew() {
        this._insertService.insertNewService(this.user)
            .toPromise()
            .then(
                response => {
                    this.result = response;
                    if (this.result.status != 200) {
                       //error message
                    } else {
                       // new element inserted and now it is in cars list API
                    }
                },
                error => console.log(error)
            );

    }
```

Now in my `car.component.html`

```
 <div *ngFor="let element of data" id="{{element.car_id}}">
    <mat-card>
        <mat-card-content>
          //some details about cars
        </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
 </div>
```

Now everything is fine for first reading, but when `insertNew()` called and inserted any new element, nothing change in carsList view.

1 - I tried to run my function using `ngZone`

```
carsList() {
            this._carsListService.carsService(this.user)
                .subscribe(
                    response => {
                    this.zone.run(() => { // <==
                            this.result = response;
                            if (this.result.code != 200) {
                                 //error response message
                            }
                            else if (this.result.code == 200) {
                                this.data = [] = this.data;
                                this.result.cars.forEach(element => {
                                    this.data.push(element);
                                });
                            }
                             console.log("using ngzone"); //this console appeared just one time even when I insert anything new
                             });
                    },
                    error => console.log(error)
                );
        }
```

2 - I tried to go with DoCheck algorithm included in Angular, it looks like
replacing this line   `<div *ngFor="let element of data" id="{{element.car_id}}">` with this   `<div *ngFor="#element of data" id="{{element.car_id}}">` but Angular said (Unexpected token #).

**#EDIT**

My service

```
carsService(value: Object) {
        return this._appService.LoadAPI(value, this.carsAPI);
    }
```

LoadAPI

```
public loadScript(src) {
        let script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(script);
        script.src = src;
    }
```

## EDIT 2

I have tried to call `carList()` function inside `insertNew()`

```
constructor( public cars_list: CarComponent)

insertNew() {
            this._insertService.insertNewService(this.user)
                .toPromise()
                .then(
                    response => {
                        this.result = response;
                        if (this.result.status != 200) {
                           //error message
                        } else {
                    this.cars_list.carsList();
                           // new element inserted and now it is in cars list API
                        }
                    },
                    error => console.log(error)
                );

        }
```

Comment: When the car is added to the list, is the `carsListService.carsService` observable / subject notified? That will need to happen for the `subscribe` function to be called, thereby updating your `data` variable

Comment: # instead of let was in angular before the final release, it's deprecated. Did you check the data after insertNew was called? Are you sure they are correct? And why do you have this in your code please? this.data = [] = this.data;

Comment: 1. It has nothing to do with zones, DoCheck, or whatever other angular internals. 2. Your service is doing it all wrong. It shouldn't subscribe and modify its state. It shouldn't even have any state. It should only return an observable, and the component should be the one subscribing. 3. Why do you think adding an element to some database on a server should auomatically refresh a list in the browser? You of course need to reload the list from the server after you've inserted the car.

Comment: @Laker Yes I checked my data and nothing wrong, and `this.data = [] = this.data` to load more button, to append the list separately.

Comment: @JBNizet My component is the one subscribing isn't it? Nothing to do with subscribe in my service, maybe I miss something, please check my edit.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread your explanation. Still, the rest of my comment still applies. You ake a request to get a list of cars. Then you make another request to add a car on the server. That won't magically refresh the list. You need to get the list from the server again, to refresh it.

Comment: @JBNizet Sure it won't magically refresh the list, I'm looking for a way to get the list from the server, I tried to call the carList API again when I'm in insertNew function, but it doesn't work and it is silly solution of course.

Comment: Why would it be a silly solution? It is the right solution.

Comment: @JBNizet Silly because when you insert new car you are calling two API's one for insert and the second to show the list again. Anyway it didn't work for me.

Comment: *It didn't work for me*: we can't help you with that. Post a complete minimal example showing what you tried, and tell us precisely what the problem is.

Comment: @JBNizet Please check my Edit 2.

Comment: @JBNizet when I console it the data is correct and the new element appeared in my console, but the problem is the element didn't shown up at the first of array, it needs refresh again.

Comment: You're calling the service, but you completely ignore what it returns. the code should basically read like `this.insertNewCar().then(() => this.loadCars());` And the loadCar() method, which should also be called at initialization time, should call the service and initialize the list of cars of the component. If you posted a complete minimal example, as a plunkr, I would be able to show you how to fix the code.

Comment: I'm calling the function in the car component, and this function should call the service by itself, how I ignore what the service returns if I already got the data correctly in my console after adding new car?
And I don't understand the loadCar() method. I can post a minimal example as a plunkr but it won't work because of API's, if it is okay with you I will make one. Thanks

Comment: @JBNizet check this please https://plnkr.co/edit/gzOujbmiRzlMbOMpi4Kv

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162251/discussion-between-roula-halabi-and-jb-nizet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to create an `Observable` that emits the data you're interested in whenever it changes. It would be managed from within a service, and any necessary components can subscribe to that `Observable`.

When you then call `insertNew`, if that API call returns the item that has been added, you can simply add that to your existing data, and notify the observable, without needing to make another API call.

By having your components subscribe to an `Observable`, they don't need to know *when* to get updated data, it's simply pushed to them. It also means that no matter which component calls the service, all components will receive the updated data via the observable

Here is an example to indicate what I mean:

```js
@Injectable()
export class CarListService {

  const root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

  // This is your data.
  private data = [];
  // This subject will be used to update the observable
  private _carList = new Subject();

  // This observable is public so that your components can subscribe
  carList$ = this._carList.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    // The notify function emits the data variable out of the observable
    // In it's initial state, it is simply an empty array
    this.notify();
  }

  loadList(): void {
    // Here, we can get our data from the API. Note that this function
    // does not return anything
    this.http.get(this.root + '/users').subscribe((res) => {
      // We update data with what comes back, and call notify again 
      // so that the observable emits the latest data
      this.data = res;
      this.notify();
    })
  }

  insertNew():void {
    // Here we are updating the API
    this.http.post(this.root + "/users", {
      name: "This is my new one"
    }).subscribe((res) => {
      // The API returns our newly created item, so append it to data, and 
      // call notify again to update the observable
      this.data.push(res);
      this.notify();
    })
  }

  private notify() {
    // Call next on the subject with the latest data
    this._carList.next(this.data);
  }
}
```

If you want to see this in action, I've created a plunker to show what I mean
https://plnkr.co/edit/lLfFcqYqawKcyi3tLtQe?p=preview

Please note that the service and component are in the same file, but that's just for the example

Comment: So I should subscribe in my service not in component?
this is huge for my project, if I will do that I will change a lot of things

Comment: The components subscribe to the observable (in this example it's `carList$`), but the service will subscribe to your HTTP calls so that it can update the `carList$` observable, and allow all of the components that are subscribed to `carList$` to get the updated data

Comment: It's easier than all that. When you insert an element, you must reload the entire list or manually push the array

Comment: @Eliseo but how does the car.component know when insert.component has added an element?